# Can't connect to ssh server by global IP address when not on the server's Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, port-forwarding, port

When on the same network it works fine with either the global or local IP address being used.

I am forwarding port 22 like this:

```
IP Address  Start Port  End Port    IP Address  Start Port  End Port    Prot
localip         22         22        globalip       22         22       BOTH
```

I made sure port 22 was open like this on the server: `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your global IP is a global IP and not another RFC 1918 private address from another range? You could have another NAT gateway upstream of you (maybe your broadband modem is acting as a NAT gateway without you realizing it), and you may need to do port forwarding on that gateway as well. What are the first two octets (dotted-decimal segments) of your gateway's WAN-side IP address?

Comment: @Spiff 72.230 is the fist two

Answer (score 0):

SSH (port 22) is one of the most-attacked ports on the Internet along with certain standard Windows file sharing ports. Some ISPs block connections to these ports by default. Check with your ISP to see if they block that by default, and if so, if they can disable it for your line/account.

Comment: Would a Port like 1000 work

Comment: @person Yes, your ISP probably doesn't block all ports, so you could set port 1000 on your NAT gateway's public IP address to forward to port 22 on your `sshd` server box. Then from your `ssh` client, remember to add `-p 1000` when connecting from outside your network. If using `scp`, note that it's `-P 1000` with a capital 'P'. Not sure why the OpenSSH developers didn't keep that the same between tools, but whatever.

Comment: I just tried it and it is still not working the connection times out after trying to connect.

Comment: etimedout (connection timed out)